# Making a text file of list of directory entries in bin

Tags: ls

How could I make a text file of the list of directory entries in `/bin/` along with the attributes of all the files stored there?

Comment: What _attributes_ are you interested in? permissions, ownership, times, size, inode, nlinks, disk usage, fragmentation, file system, ACL, extended attributes, file flags, content based ones like type of executable, linked dlls...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use I/O redirection , writing output of ls command to a file solves this.

```
ls -la /bin > files.txt
```

Comment: what about the subdirectories?

Comment: @Thushi, the OP asked for _directory entries_ in the `/bin` file. There's no mention of subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find`:

```
find /bin -ls > file.txt
```

Since the directories in `/bin` are almost certain to not contain spaces or strange characters, a simple `ls` redirected to a file should also work:

```
ls -l /bin > file.txt
```

Unlike the `find` above, this will not show subdirectories nor hidden files. To get those as well, you can use:

```
ls -Ral /bin > file.txt
```